# Tiger WOIS Could not open workflow

Tags: saga, tiger, workflow, sentinel-1

Recently I have been trying to use the TIGER WOIS package which looks really useful. I'm trying to use the Flood mapping tool with Sentinel-I data, but I encountered a problem right away.

In the first step of the pre-processing (WOIS Workflow 1c - Sentinel I) I get the following error: "Failed to initialize velocity engine". In the History and Log I see that I have errors for **all** SAGA and Workflow algorithms (error in line...) and this is probably why I run into this mistake (I guess?). Did I do something wrong with the installation of Tiger WOIS or should I make some changes in my settings somewhere?